# python program won't print prompts in order

Tags: python, prompt

```
count=1
while count<6:
   number1=int(input('Enter first number: '))
   count+=1
   if count==2:
     number2=int(input('Enter second number: '))
     count+=1
   elif count==3:
     number3=int(input('Enter third number: '))
     count+=1
   elif count==4:
        number4=int(input('Enter fourth number: '))
        count+=1
   elif count==5:
        number5=int(input('Enter fifth number: '))
        count+=1
   else:
        print('                            ')
```

When I run this it prompts 1st number then 2nd the 4th then 1st. What am I doing wrong that it's not in order 1 to 5? Thanks.

Comment: normal, each time you enter your loop you increase value. first time 1+1 = 2, if == 2 you add 1 then 3 when you reenter the loop +1 then 4 ... etc.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works as expected:

```
count=0
while count<6:
   count+=1
   if count == 1:
       number1=int(input('Enter first number: '))
   elif count==2:
     number2=int(input('Enter second number: '))
   elif count==3:
     number3=int(input('Enter third number: '))
   elif count==4:
        number4=int(input('Enter fourth number: '))
   elif count==5:
        number5=int(input('Enter fifth number: '))
   else:
        print('                            ')
```

The reason your code didn't is because the loop will evaluate the code and then continue, IE when count == 2 only that statement would run in that loop; after that the loop would run again which would again display

> Enter first number:

also, because you add 1 to your counter variable at the start AND when the input is given you are adding 2 for each loop

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the add the condition in case of the first entry.

I would rewrite it this way:

```
count=1
while count<6:
    if count==1:
        number1=int(input('Enter first number: '))
        count+=1
    if count==2:
        number2=int(input('Enter second number: '))
        count+=1
    if count==3:
        number3=int(input('Enter third number: '))
        count+=1
    if count==4:
        number4=int(input('Enter fourth number: '))
        count+=1
    if count==5:
        number5=int(input('Enter fifth number: '))
        count+=1
    else:
        print('                            ')
```

Comment: I'd prefer the elif for efficiency sake; that way it will not continue to evaluate after the case is met. This also adds allot of non-pretty code due to incrementing count only when an if statement is met  (however this might be a good thing depending on what the user is trying to accomplish)

Comment: Yes, good point. Although in this particular case efficiency is not an issue and I really find `if` much more beautiful than `elif`.

Comment: True, I've always hated the ascetics or 'elif'

Answer (score 0):

You might find this shorter and more useful for future projects of the same kind:

```
orderingList=['first','second','third','fourth','fifth']
numbers = []
for i in range(len(orderingList)):
    ordering = orderingList[i]
    number = int(input('Enter '+ordering+' number: '))
    numbers.append(number)
print(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include the 1st number inside an if statement. Also, count+=1 is unnecessary to be repeated so much. If you want to do it this way something like this would be fine:

```
count = 1

while count < 6:
   if count ==1:
       number1=int(input('Enter first number: '))
   if count==2:
     number2=int(input('Enter second number: '))
   elif count==3:
     number3=int(input('Enter third number: '))
   elif count==4:
        number4=int(input('Enter fourth number: '))
   elif count==5:
        number5=int(input('Enter fifth number: '))
   else:
        print('                            ')

   count += 1
```